Vsphere Vcenter AVI Load Balancer - SE cant connect to Controller
Tthe SE's are unable to join controller and i am unable to figure out what is happening.
I have console access to the SE but the admin / admin doesn't works for me.
my controller version is 30.2.2-9108.
Output of https:///api/securechannel-status?is_controller=false
{"count": 2, "results": [{"_last_modified": "1729534976401619", "is_controller": false, "marked_for_delete": false, "name": "se-b00dcc3a-5b6a-4a52-8e6c-740cd6733e05", "status": "SECURE_CHANNEL_NONE", "uuid": "se-b00dcc3a-5b6a-4a52-8e6c-740cd6733e05", "url": "https://10.65.41.160/api/securechannelmapping/se-b00dcc3a-5b6a-4a52-8e6c-740cd6733e05"}, {"_last_modified": "1729534976404044", "is_controller": false, "marked_for_delete": false, "name": "se-994c00e4-3754-47d5-b72b-c303daa0727b", "status": "SECURE_CHANNEL_NONE", "uuid": "se-994c00e4-3754-47d5-b72b-c303daa0727b", "url": "https://10.65.41.160/api/securechannelmapping/se-994c00e4-3754-47d5-b72b-c303daa0727b"}]}
Any pointers on login credentials OR secure channel is appreciated. My gut feeling is that IP address is not assigned to the SE as i am unable to ping it from the controller when connected using SSH.
TIA
Hitesh

Rebooting the SE
Rebooting the controllers
Recreated service and engines


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
